# If main window is adjustable by size and position can it is possible to open dialog box always at center of main window?

Tags: java, swt, jface

```
shell = new Shell(getParent(), getStyle());
shell.setText("Key Information");
Shell primary = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell();
Rectangle bounds = primary.getBounds();
Rectangle rect = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell().getBounds();
int x = bounds.x + (bounds.width - rect.width) / 2;
int y = bounds.y + (bounds.height - rect.height) / 2;
shell.setLocation(x + 350, y + 100);
createContents();
shell.pack();
shell.open();
```

1. As above code gives approximate center position for dialog box. If I change size or position of main window dialog box not get at center position.open() gives dialog box details.
2. As main window position moves to corner dialog box must open within monitor only.

Comment: Centering is the default behavior for a JFace Dialog except that it also remembers where it was last opened.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. At 1) there is no question and at 2) is not clear: you want to center a SWT dialog in the parent keeping it in the same monitor?